# maximum number of NIC(Network Interface Controller) connection?

Tags: network-adapter, network-interface, usb-network-adapter

I'd like to know if there's maximum number of NIC connected in a Windows PC.

By expanding `USB 3.0 ports` and connecting a lot of `USB 3.0 type network adapter` into it, 
can we connect limitless number of NIC into one PC?

I checked [similar question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/nic-limit-in-kernels-325256/) with me and someone said `several thousand` can possible, but It's about linux system.

***Question:***

1. Is there limit number of NIC connection?
2. If so, what factors have a decisive effect on the limit number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many slots does the server have that can hold your NICs?
How many ports on each NIC?
Multiply those two numbers and that's your maximum.
There is no practical limit on the number of devices that connect to
Windows Server.
The limitation is generally what the physical server can hold,
and the documented limits are generally what has been tested in the largest
server configuration that could be assembled to test it.

Because of these facts, there are very few publications about these limits,
as nobody ever managed (or bothered) to assemble a large enough test bed.

Microsoft publishes some numbers for specific configurations:

- For Windows server inside Hyper-V, the
  [published limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-hyper-v-scalability-in-windows-server)
  is 12 for Windows Server 2016 and 68 for Windows Server 2019.
- The
  [Windows Server 2016 NIC and Switch Embedded Teaming User Guide](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Windows-Server-2016-839cb607)
  mentions a limit of 32 NICs in a team.

However, these limits are specific to certain software configurations or products.
There is no published hard limit that pertains to Windows in general,
so there is probably none such, so only physical constraints apply in practice.

If you ever try to test the NIC limit, you would run into too many limits
to count: Financial, test space, computer case, computer bus-transfer
limit, CPU limit, network bandwidth limit, routers number limit and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> By expanding USB 3.0 ports and connecting a lot of USB 3.0 type network adapter into it,
> can we connect limitless number of NIC into one PC?

No - the USB Spec gives you a maximum number of devices per root hub. Including any hubs you have in between, that's 127 - even assuming you had the bandwidth for all those connections.

You would also have to power all these devices - which means powered hubs

Fundamentally, there's no really sane reason to do it

A smarter way to do it would be to start with something that'll give you fundamentally more bandwidth - maybe a multi-port gigabit ethernet adaptors or better yet 10 gbe connection upstream. You could experiment with virtual adaptors, vlans and such.

Then get more ports with a switch as you ought to. There's little reason for dozens or hundreds of physical ethernet ports on a PC

Comment: The limit of 127 per root hub exists, but I don't think there is a limit to the number of root hubs.

Comment: maybe but the very core premise of the question, of *thousands* of physical *USB*  adaptors is flawed. And smacks of trying to tighten bolts with a hammer. And there are better/more intelligent ways to do it

Comment: I think this is theoretical, not something the poster really intends trying (unless willing to spend a very large sum perhaps for nothing).

Comment: Probably It was my bad assumption of expanding `USB ports` infinitely. This question was meant ask if OS/Board-dependent constraint is exist in connecting NIC (aside from USB connection related problems). But still, your approach was also helpful for me.